# Corn Field Classification: Layer error: No valid training data were found

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, random-forest

I have a code in GEE for crop mapping. I also have the shape of training points. but after running I faced an error: No valid training data were found.
Please Help me how can I fix the code?

The training shape file: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ee-bbahmanabadi123/assets/Mize_GCP_Tr_1400-1401

The code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b977db28eb47b7aa8f699211d71acba8

```
// Load the satellite image collection for the desired time period
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  .filterBounds(aoi)
  .filterDate('2020-07-01', '2020-10-28')
  .sort('system:time_start', false)
  .select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12']);


// Prompt the user to define the spectral indices thresholds
var ndviThreshold = 0.5//parseFloat(prompt('Enter the NDVI threshold:'));
var laiThreshold = 6 //parseFloat(prompt('Enter the LAII threshold:'));

// Calculate the spectral indices (e.g., NDVI, NDWI) for the image collection
var withIndices = collection.map(function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  var lai = image.expression('-log((3.8-(((1 + L) * (NIR - RED)) / (NIR + RED + L)))/(3.66))/(0.018)',
    {
      'NIR': image.select('B8'),
      'RED': image.select('B4'),
      'L': 0.5
    }
  ).rename('LAI'); // Fix the typo here
  return image.addBands([ndvi, lai]);
});
// Filter the image collection based on spectral index thresholds
var cornMask = withIndices.map(function(image) {
  var ndviMask = image.select('NDVI').gt(ndviThreshold);
  var laiMask = image.select('LAI').lt(laiThreshold);
  
  var cornFieldMask = ndviMask.multiply(laiMask);
  
  return image.updateMask(cornFieldMask);
});

// Convert the training data to image masks
var trainingMask = ee.Image().toByte().paint(trainingData, 1);

// Combine the corn field mask and training mask using AND operation
var finalMask = cornMask.select('LAI','NDVI').reduce(ee.Reducer.allNonZero()).and(trainingMask);

// Sample the final mask using random points within the AOI
var trainingSamples = finalMask.sample({
  region: aoi,
  scale: 100,
  numPixels: 1000,
  geometries: true
});

// Train a random forest classifier
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10)
  .setOutputMode('REGRESSION')
  .train(trainingSamples, 'Product');

// Classify the final mask using the trained classifier
var classified = finalMask.classify(classifier);

// Display the classified map
Map.addLayer(classified, {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['white', 'green']}, 'Corn Field Classification');

// Calculate the area of corn fields within the AOI
var areaImage = classified.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());

// Reduce the image to calculate the total area of corn fields within the AOI
var totalArea = areaImage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: aoi,
  scale: 100,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});

// Get the area value from the result
var cornFieldArea = ee.Number(totalArea.get('classification'));

// Convert the area to hectares
var cornFieldAreaHectares = cornFieldArea.divide(10000);

// Print the total area of corn fields within the AOI
print('Total area of corn fields within the AOI (in hectares):', cornFieldAreaHectares);
```

Comment: It seems like your LAI image is giving values that are way too high. I'm guessing you should apply that equation after you scaled the band values (divide by 10000)..  Also, I'm wondering if in the filter that you used for LAI did you really mean to use less than (.lt)?